# How to fetch questions ony by one on save and next buttons

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a quiz management system and need to fetch the data from the database and displaying the data one by one on clicking next button.

I want to use ajax to insert data into database after clicking next button by using file read and write function.

---

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_question WHERE setid='$set' AND status=1 ORDER BY RAND()");

while($sha=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    <h4><? echo $sha['id'];?></h4>
```

Comment: and where is `ajax` code? also headsup SQL Injection is surrounding that query of yours

Comment: So you want us to write the ajax code for you? This will not be possible please post your attempt so that we can correct you out.

Comment: can u just show me how to fetch questions one by one by clicking on next button. plz suggest some

Answer (score 0):

here's simple way to do it 
first get question from database then put a button to the next id

```
<?php 
$rows = 0;
$id = isset($_GET['id'] ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `tbl_question` WHERE `tbl_question`.`status` = 1 AND  `tbl_question`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1';
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$something,$something_else,$status);
while($stmt->fetch()) 
     $rows++;
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

if($rows === 0) {
 echo 'qustion not found';
} else {

   // output qustion 

   // button 

   echo '<a type="buttton" href="?id=' . $id + 1 . '">next</a>';
}
```

Comment: what if i am getting some ids in an php array.. and i want to display all those ids question on save and next pattern. use js for this purpose

Comment: you can select all ids in a different query and save em inside of an array 
$query = 'SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_question`';